# multiple GIT repos, adding an existing project to GIT

Tags: git, github

I have Two issues:

1. I have two separate repos (network Team Foundation Server, GitHub)

   I have several projects in a /wamp/www/ folder on my system, where they are served up. They go to the Git repo on the network.

   I have a new project, which I want to put into my *personal* GitHub repo. I'm not sure what will happen if I simply add/commit/push. Pretty sure it'll end up in the default TFS repo. How do I point it at my own personal repo?
2. putting an existing project into my repo

   GitHub has several options for starting a new project, but it doesn't seem to have an option for dropping in an existing project.

   The project is *already* within Git (since my www folder is Git init'd) so I can't simply git init it. (git init treats my project folder as if it is empty.)

**UPDATE**

This:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by dropping in an existing project here?

Comment: Sorry, I have added a diagram to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to push your code to a GitHub repository in addition to your TFS repository?

The solution is to add another "remote". The initial repository you clone will link your local git to the remote called "origin". What you want to do if you want to push your repository to another server is to add a remote.

To do this, do the following:

```
git remote add github https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
git push -u github master
```

Where "github" is the name of the remote you'll want. Call it something that makes sense to you, it can be anything. Then, when you'll want to push/pull from the "origin" remote, you'll be able to do a `git push` or `git push origin`, and if you'll want to push to the other remote, simply do a `git push github`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't mean "in addition to" I mean "instead of". I have added a diagram to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your diagram. With Git, you usually have one repository per project. If I understand your diagram correctly, you already have two project in the same repository, is that correct?

Comment: That's what I'm not entirely sure of. Git is active on the www directory (I can run git commands there). All my TFS projects go between their various directories and their various repos in TFS. I'm afraid that, if I push my personal project, it will end up in the TFS repo instead of my personal GutHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear for me what is the relation between project, repositories and "wampt/www" folder but the most probably solution with that information could be:

1. try make a look to git-submodules. They allow include 3rd party git repos into git project e.g. your personal repo into company repos
2. if there are no folder/file conflicts - the easiest way could be use git-remote to add 3rd party repo to you cloned repository; merge them and update/reorganize folder structure as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I have added a diagram to clarify.

Comment: @da thanks, about issue 1, mentioned git sub-modules may fit you requirements. You will have separate history/branching and sub-module will be something like "reference" to other project.

Comment: @DaveC426913 about point 2, if you want split existing git folder into 2 repositories, where one will be in TFS and second in Github, then this may help you [filter a folder into new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) and then you can add them as sub-module